# Angular, recorrer un Array en Typescript

Tags: array, angular, typescript, ngfor

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para aprender Angular. El tutorial propone el siguiente código en el archivo typeScript:

```
  entradas!: object[]; //entradas!: object[];  entradas: object[] = [];

  constructor() {

    this.entradas = [
      { titulo: "Python cada dia más presente" },
      { titulo: "Java presente desde hace más de 20 años" },
      { titulo: "JavaScript cada vez más funcional" },
      { titulo: "Kotlin potencia para tus apps" },
      { titulo: "Donde quedó Pascal?" },
    ]
  }
```

entradas es un array cuyo property título quiero recorrer en el html usando la directiva *ngFor :

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let entrada of entradas">{{entrada.titulo}}</li>
</ul>
```

Sin embargo, este código me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Property 'titulo' does not exist on type 'object'.ngtsc(2339)
empleados.component.ts(5, 36): Error occurs in the template of component EmpleadosComponent.
```

En el tutorial la directiva *ngFor funciona bien y muestra las entradas del array, sin embargo en mi proyecto devuelve el error que he indicado.

Answer (score 1):

Es porque `object` no tiene una propiedad llamada `titulo`. Se puede resolver el error especificando cuál es el tipo de la colección:

```
entradas!: {titulo: string}[];
```

Ahí se le indica al compilador que `entradas` es una colección de objetos con una propiedad llamada `titulo`.

Comment: Ahora si que ha funcionado, declarando el array como dices. Gracias